# why the order of my output doesn't change even if i change my pthread_join() place

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, pthreads

**why do I get the same output order when  `pthread_join( thread3, NULL);` comes before `pthread_join( thread1, NULL);`
and when:
`pthread_join( thread1, NULL);` comes before  `pthread_join( thread3, NULL);`**

I know that `pthread_join()` waits for the thread to terminate and it worked on thread 2 but why it doesn't work here like I waited for thread 3 to terminate but it still terminates after thread 1 terminate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * print_message_function( void *ptr );
void * do_something_else(  );
void * a_new_function();


int main()
{
     pthread_t thread1, thread2,thread3,thread4;

     char *message1 = "Thread 1   is running ";
     char *message2 = "Thread 2";
     int  iret1, iret2,iret3;

     void * (*f_ptr)();
     f_ptr = do_something_else; 

    

    /* Create independent threads each of which will execute function */

          iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, print_message_function, (void*) message1);



          iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, f_ptr/*do_something_else*/, NULL);

              pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 
     

        
          iret3 = pthread_create( &thread3, NULL,a_new_function , NULL);
         
     pthread_join( thread3, NULL); //--------------here-------------------------------

    pthread_join( thread1, NULL); //---------------here-------------------------------
   
     return 0;
}

void * print_message_function( void *ptr )
{
    int i;     
   
    for(int i=0; i < 1; i++)
       printf("%s \n", (char *)ptr);
}
void * a_new_function(){

int a;
int b;
int c;
a=5;b=7;
c=b+a;
printf ("the value of c =%d\n",c);

return 0;
}
void * do_something_else(  )
{
    int i;     
    
    for(int i=0; i < 1;  i++)
       printf("%s \n", "this is do_something_else function");
}
```

the output in both ways is:

**this is do_something_else function

Thread 1   is running

the value of c =12**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pthread_join does not affect the scheduling of the thread that you are joining with; really it is just a way to cleanup resources and retrieve exit status.
In your example, the only dependency is that `thread 2` will complete before `thread 3`, since you do not create `thread 3` until you have joined `thread 2`.

This has no effect on `thread 1`; and the order of the final joins is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

"Waiting for X" is just waiting until X happens. "Waiting for Y" is just waiting until Y happens. Until either X or Y happens, there is no difference between waiting for X and waiting for Y. It's not clear why you think it makes any difference which thread you wait for. Waiting has no effect on the things that you are waiting for. It just waits for them to finish.